# Printing Two Multidimensional Arrays in PHP with Custom Loop Side by Side

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

I have two multidimensional arrays in PHP that sometimes become 4 levels deep.

These arrays are built from JSON APIs and need to be printed side by side in a table in order to be compared on a daily basis.

So far I have used a custom recursive loop to print them because array_walk_recursive wouldn't print them side in table  tags with the ability to customize the loop.

This is my loop:

```
 function pretty_dump($arr, $d=1){
                if ($d==1) echo "<pre>";    // HTML Only
                if (is_array($arr)){
                    foreach($arr as $k=>$v){
                        for ($i=0;$i<$d;$i++){
                            echo "_";
                        }
                        if (is_array($v)){
                            echo '<span class="red">'. $k.PHP_EOL . "</span>";
                            Pretty_Dump($v, $d+1);
                        } else {
                            echo '<span class="label"><strong>' . $k . "</strong>" ."</span>"."\t".'<span 
                            class="value">'.$v.PHP_EOL. "</span>";
                        }
                        
                    }
                }
                if ($d==1) echo "</pre>";   // HTML Only
```

Then I call the array like this, inside the table:

```
                 <tr>
                    <td>
                        <?
                            pretty_dump ($result);
                        ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?
                            pretty_dump ($result2);
                        ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?
                            pretty_dump ($result3);
                        ?>
                    </td>
                    
                </tr>
```

My issue here is that I need to compare all three arrays ($result, $result2, $result3) with the keys of $result (first array). I need the table to be setup in a way so that if there isn't a value for a certain key in $result there should be an NA or blank in the column next to $result.

For example if $result2 doesn't have a value for a corresponding $result key, it should print a NA in that td tag for $result2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so after lots of trial and error, I figured this out:

I flattened the arrays and picked out the pieces I wanted one by one, please see the working code below:

```
<?
                $GLOBALS['seconddata'] = $result2; 
                $GLOBALS['thirddata'] = $result3;
                $GLOBALS['fourthdata'] = $finalresults5;



            function pretty_dump($arr, $d=1, $parentKey=null) {
               
                    function flatten($array, $prefix = '') {
                        $return = [];
                        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
                            if (is_array($value)) {
                                
                                $return = array_merge($return, flatten($value, $prefix . $key . '_'));
                            } else {
                                $tableRow = "<tr>";

                                $brackets = $prefix . $key;
                                

                                $tableRow .= "<td id='Firstdata'> {$brackets} </td>";
                                
                                $tableRow .= "<td> {$value} </td>";
                                $splitResult = explode("_", $brackets);
                                
                                $output = $GLOBALS['seconddata'];
                                $output2 = $GLOBALS['thirddata'];
                                $output3 = $GLOBALS['fourthdata'];

                                
                                  
                                foreach( $splitResult as $key2 => $value2){
                                     

                                    if(isset($output[$value2])){
                                        $output = $output[$value2];
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        $output = '<span class="red">Non-Existant</span>';
                                    }

                                    if(isset($output2[$value2])){
                                        $output2 = $output2[$value2];
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        $output2 = '<span class="red">Non-Existant</span>';
                                    }
                                    

                                    

                                }
                                
                                if(isset($output3[$brackets])){
                                    $output3 = $output3[$brackets];
                                }
                                else{
                                    $output3 = '<span class="red">Non-Existant</span>';
                                }
                                $difVal = "";
                                if($output != $value){
                                    $difVal = "difference-cell"; 
                                }
                                $tableRow .= '<td id="seconddata" class="' . $difVal . '" >' . $output . "</td>";
                                

                                
                                $tableRow .= '<td id="thirddata">' . $output2 . "</td>";
                               
                                $tableRow .= '<td id="fourthdata">' . $output3 . "</td>";

                                $tableRow .= "</tr>";
                                echo $tableRow;
                            }
                        }
                        return $return;
                    }

                    flatten($arr);
            }
            
                        
        ?>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>First Data Keys</th>
                    <th>First Data Values</th>
                    <th>Second Data Values</th>
                    <th>Third Data Values</th>
                    <th>Fourth Data Values</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>


                <?
                    pretty_dump ($result);
                ?>




            </tbody>
        </table>
```

This code takes data sources, prints them with their keys into a table and compares them and colors the difference in their values.